# How to create last 30 days file's tar

Tags: linux, find, tar

How to create **tar** of last **30 days** file ?
Do anyone have idea about this
Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple command

```
$find ~ -mtime -30 | xargs tar -cvf Tar_File.tar

Explanation:    

find     -- To find the files recursively
-mtime   -- specified the modification time of last 30 days  
xargs    --The given output is passed as an input using pipe  |  and xargs convert
            all  input as an arguments .
tar      --tar comand tar the files
```

Comment: I would not use this. If you have sufficient files modified in the last 30 days that `xargs` decides to split this into two commands, bad things will happen... Assuming you have GNU `tar`, using the `-T <file_list>` option or the `--newer=` or `--after-date=` options would be much better...